# Apache Server not sending cgi script output to client until script completion

Tags: ajax, apache

I have a set of scripts that were working on an old apache server that needed to be moved to a new install. Now the Ajax request is not showing data in the div until the whole script is complete. With the same browsers I can point to the old server - works. Point to new server - doesn't.
Same behavior with Chrome, Firefox, and IE. Looking at TCPDUMP on the new server I do not see any packets leaving server until script is complete.

Is there a way to get the apache to send data as it occurs instead of waiting till the script completes?
(really, what is the way, as my old apache server does this)

Version information:
Working old version:
Server version: Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   Feb 14 2012 18:09:18

Newer broken version:
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Server built:   Mar  4 2013 22:05:16

Comment: Script language/code?  Apache/scripting language integration?  Configuration files?

Comment: Here is the CGI script I am running: #!/usr/bin/perl -w
print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";
print "Sending 3 pings to Victim";
print "<br/>";
$cmd = "sudo ping victim -c 3 -W 1";
system($cmd);

Comment: Apache/scripting language integration: I don't know what you mean here.

Comment: It was the deflate module - editted out all the config lines from deflate.conf and my scripts work on new server.